# how to select row index and variable name based on value in a data frame?

Tags: dataframe, select, conditional-statements, row, key-value

I have a large data frame made of float numbers between -1.0 and 1.0. I would like to create a new list containing the index rows, the variable names and the values for all the cells having a number higher than 0.59.

Here is an example:

```
      A      B      C    D  ...    FD
0   0.34   -0.23   0.6  0.7 ...   0.3
1   -0.5    0.99   0.8  0.2 ...   0.8
...
45  0.8   0.13    0.34  0.4 ...  -0.9

    output:
    0  C  0.6
    0  D  0.7
    1  B  0.99
    1  C  0.8
...
    1 FD  0.8
    etc..
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there must be a better solution than mine, as mine has awful performance (iterating cell by cell). But here is my attempt:

```
# creating a sample df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))

new_list = []

for tup in df.itertuples():
    for i in range(1, len(tup)):
        if tup[i] > 0.59:
            new_list.append([tup.Index, df.columns[i-1], tup[i]])             

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_list, columns=['index', 'column', 'value'])
new_df = new_df.set_index('index')
```